# In jmockit, how can I mock a void method to throw an Exception on the first call and not to on subsequent calls?

Tags: java, jmockit

I can make a void method throw an exception like this:

```
class TestClass {
    public void send(int a) {};
}

@Mocked
private TestClass mock;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    new Expectations() {
        {
            mock.send(var1);
            this.result = new Exception("some exception");
        }
    };
}
```

however, if I want the void method to throw an exception on the first call, but not on subsequent calls, these approaches do not seem to work:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    new Expectations() {
        {
            mock.send(var1);
            this.result = new Exception("some exception");
            this.result = null;
        }
    };
}
```

or

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    new Expectations() {
        {
            mock.send(var1);
            results(new Exception("some exception"), new Object());
        }
    };
}
```

They both result in no exception being thrown.

Is this possible with JMockit?  It's not clear to me from the docs [here](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Expectations.html#returns-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) and [here](http://jmockit.org/api1x/mockit/Expectations.html#result).

Answer (score 1):

The following test works fine for me:

```
static class TestClass { void send(int a) {} }
@Mocked TestClass mock;
int var1 = 1;

@Test
public void test() {
    new Expectations() {{
        mock.send(var1);
        result = new Exception("some exception");
        result = null;
    }};

    try { mock.send(var1); fail(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    mock.send(var1);
}
```