# How can I mock a void method exception using JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-test, jmockit

I have a problem when trying to mock void method exception.

```
    @Test
public void throwInternalServerException() throws Exception {
    new NonStrictExpectations() {{
        mockedClassInstance.voidMethod("abc", "def");
        result = new ServiceException();
    }};

    mockMvc.perform(post("/someRestApi/"))
            .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());
```

In the codes above, its success if i replace params **"abc"** and **"def"** with **anyString**

I tried the solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095108/in-jmockit-how-can-i-mock-a-void-method-to-throw-an-exception-on-the-first-call) but it does not work.

Any solution?

I used library : jmockit and spring-test.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `anystring` is used in the scenario, when whatever be the parameters(in this case, 'abc' and 'def'), it will throw the exception.